# Python lambda expression not doing what is expected

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list. Each entry is another list with entries, one being the names of the nodes, and the other entry being the corresponding node weights.

```
l = [ [['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], [2, 4, 3, 2]], [['E', 'F'], [3, 66]] ]
```

I want to sort the list in decreasing order based on the sum of the weights for each node. So for this example, `['E', 'F']` entry will come first because `3 + 66 > 2 + 4 + 3 + 2`

I wrote a lambda expression like so:

`l.sort(key=lambda x: x if not x[1] else sum(x[1]))`

But it is not giving me the right answer. For every `x` in `l` you have two entries `0` and `1`, `1` being the list of weights, so I am giving that to `sum` function so sort it but it is giving me the wrong answer.

Comment: In general, if you're having problems with a function you defined with a complicated `lambda`, just pull it out into a named function you define with `def`. Then you can break the expression up into separate statements, which you can step through in the debugger, or `print` out, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `sort` method sorts from smallest to largest. If you want the opposite, use `reverse=True`.

Second, the `max` function returns the largest value, not the sum of all values. If you want the sum, use `sum`.

Third, falling back to `x` if `x[1]` is empty doesn't seem to make any sense. If there are no weights, you want to treat the list of a list of names and an empty list as if it were a sum of weights? That can't be right.<sup>*</sup> Maybe you want to treat that as 0, or something larger than all numbers, or… well, whatever you want, you can write it easily. In fact, if what you want is 0, that's already the default value for `sum`.

So, to sort in the order implied by `3 + 66 > 2 + 4 + 3 + 2`:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: sum(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

---

For example:

```
>>> l = [[[], []], [['E', 'F'], [3, 66]], [[], []], [['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], [2, 4, 3, 2]]]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: sum(x[1]), reverse=True)
>>> l
[[['E', 'F'], [3, 66]], [['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], [2, 4, 3, 2]], [[], []], [[], []]]
```

---

<sub>* Python 2.x will valiantly compare `[[], []]` and `0` for you. The language requires that either `[[], []]` will be larger than all numbers, or smaller than all numbers. If you're using CPython 2.7, it will be larger, because of its own particular rules that you really don't want to learn, and definitely don't want to rely on here. Python 3.x will resist the temptation to do something silly and instead just raise a `TypeError`.</sub>

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I have some entries that have an empty node_list and an empty corresponding node_weight list. When I sort it according to that, they are being treated as "higher" than the highest list, shouldnt they be the lowest because the sum of the empty list is 0?

Comment: For example `[[[], []], [['E', 'F'], [3, 66]], [[], []], [['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], [2, 4, 3, 2]]]` is sorting to `[[[], []], [[], []], [['E', 'F'], [3, 66]], [['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], [2, 4, 3, 2]]]` - shouldn't the empty ones go at the end because they are 0?

Comment: @Ogen: In Python 2.x, whether a list of two empty lists is smaller than all numbers or larger than all numbers is not defined, just that it will be one or the other. (In CPython 2.7, it will be larger than all numbers, because, under the covers, if it can't guess how to compare two values of different types, it just compares their types by name.) In Python 3.x, instead of guessing, you'll get an exception.

Comment: @Ogen: Anyway, if you do what I suggested in the code, those empty lists will sort as 0, instead of as `[[], []]`, which means the problem goes away—they sort to the end, just as you wanted.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying, they are sorting to zero but they aren't being pushed to the end. The list is supposed to end up in decreasing order based on the weight sum. If the weight sum of the empty lists is 0, they should be at the very end but they are at the start instead. What gives?

Comment: @Ogen: If I run exactly the code I posted, on exactly the list from your comment, in either Python 2.7 or Python 3.4, I get exactly the result you asked for, with the empty ones at the end, not the beginning.

Comment: @abarnet yup you were right, it was a small mistake on my part. Accepted.